# Word for the sound produced while walking down the stairs

Tags: single-word-requests, sounds

Here, I want the word pertaining to the sound of human footsteps while walking down the stairs. The word I am looking for, can be contrasted with the word of the sound of footsteps of [army marching](https://www.maxpixel.net/Marching-Military-Armed-Army-Soldiers-Uniform-2898014). I am just looking for that word that denotes the sound of footsteps (hitting on the stairs) while walking down the stairs.

My research suggests two best options; one is adjective to describe that sort of sound, and the other, noun:

**1.** Click-clacking sound.

**2.** [Clomp](https://www.maxpixel.net/Marching-Military-Armed-Army-Soldiers-Uniform-2898014).

I am not fully satisfied with the word clomp as it denotes the sound of a **heavy** tread.

> I heard the ______ of her footsteps when she was walking down the stairs.
>
> [image: picture of a woman walking down the stairs]

Comment: (a) Those particular shoes in the illustration will neither click-clack nor clomp.(b) What's wrong with the word *sound* in your sentence? Or are you wanting a word which will render the "walking down the stairs" part redundant?

Comment: @AndrewLeach, (a) I've replaced the image; hope it works. (b) because the word **sound** doesn't specify the sound which I am looking for ... and I'm not wanting a word which will render the "walking down the stairs" part redundant, but I know that I could say "step down the stairs."

Comment: I would tend to say' the (click) clack of her boots/high-heels on the stairs' rather than the clack of her footsteps.

Comment: Contrast to marching army, stairs reference: deescalation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re looking for a single word that specifically means
the sound of *human* footsteps ***while walking down the stairs***,
I suspect that you’re going to be disappointed. 
English has quite a few niche words,
but you’ve presented a very rarefied specification,
and I doubt that there’s a word with that narrow a meaning. 
But if you’ll be satisfied by a word that *can* be used to refer to that,
then I suggest ***tread***:

> [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/tread):
>
>   A manner or the sound of someone walking.
>   *‘I heard the heavy tread of Dad’s boots’*
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tread):
>
>   A person’s
>   **tread**
>   is the sound that they make with their feet as they walk.
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/tread_2):
>
>   `British`
>   the sound that someone makes when they walk

Macmillan says that this is a Br.E. meaning / usage. 
I question that; I’ve lived in the U.S. all my life
(with only a few days spent in the U.K.) and it popped right into my head. 
Then again, I mainly know it from
[With Cat-Like Tread, (Upon Our Prey We Steal)](https://www.gsarchive.net/pirates/web_op/pirates25.html),
from [*The Pirates of Penzance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pirates_of_Penzance) by [Gilbert and Sullivan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_and_Sullivan):

> With cat-like tread,
>      Upon our prey we steal;
>   In silence dread,
>      Our cautious way we feel.
>   No sound at all,
>      We never speak a word,
>   A fly’s foot-fall
>      Would be distinctly heard –

Answer (score 2):

If the sound is not necessarily high-pitched (ruling out "click") and is not heavy (ruling out "clomp"), then you might use **tapping** or **patter** (repeated tapping) or [**pitter-patter**/**pit-a-pat**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pitter-patter).

Answer (score 2):

*"I heard the tip-tap  of her footsteps..."*

> [Tip-tap](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tip-tap) (noun) (M-W Dictionary)
>
> an alternating light knocking or tapping; also : the sound made by
>   such tapping

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat archaic, or at least obscure, word is ***footfall***:

> [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/footfall):
>
>   The sound of a footstep or footsteps.
>   *‘ you will recognize his footfall on the stairs’*
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=footfall):
>
>   See
>   **footstep**
>   .
>       [***footstep***](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=footstep)
>       :
>         The sound of a foot stepping
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/footfall):
>
>   A
>   **footfall**
>   is the sound that is made by someone
>     walking each time they take a step.
>   *She heard Tom’s familiar, flat footfall on the staircase.*

I didn’t find a dictionary that identifies *footfall* as archaic or obscure,
but Collins and [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/footfall) call it “literary”. 
I probably wouldn’t have thought of it, but I saw it in the lyrics of
[With Cat-Like Tread (Upon Our Prey We Steal)](https://www.gsarchive.net/pirates/web_op/pirates25.html),
from [*The Pirates of Penzance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pirates_of_Penzance) by [Gilbert and Sullivan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_and_Sullivan):

> ︙
>   No sound at all,
>      We never speak a word,
>   A fly’s foot-fall
>      Would be distinctly heard –